# Constantly shuting down

Tags: fan

I am new to Ubuntu, so please excuse me, if this is a silly question.

I have a Toshiba U500 - 10E, with Windows 8 32bit installed.
I have installed Ubuntu 64bit but while running it, the fans of the laptop are always turned on although I was not even working with Inkscape or Gimp.

After talking with my friends, I uninstalled Ubuntu 64bit and started working with the 32bit version. But today I was just working for 1h50m maximum, after that my fan starts working again and the laptop shuts down.

With Windows 8 everything worked perfectly, only when I installed Ubuntu it started doing this, any suggestions?

If you need more details about graphics card, processor or laptop in general, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y sensord
```

Use this to see what temp your computer is running. Chances are its an overheating problem.
Run `sensors` command after installing sensord and you should see something like this

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:         +0.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +54.6°C  (high = +70.0°C)
```

If you want to know a little more about the program before you install it run `apt-cache show sensord`

Comment: Thank you rebelsoul,my laptop and I just turned it on 10m ago have the follow information from sensor:


Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +42.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +41.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)


I cleaned yesterday the laptop, possibly I have to change the ?thermal paste? from the laptop right?

Comment: do something resource heavy on your computer and monitor the temp

Comment: I noticed you said you had windows 32 bit installed before, is your sys 32 0r 64 bit?